# Is it possible to make airflow use a different python environment?

Tags: python-3.x, environment-variables, airflow

I used apache/airflow:2.3.3 docker image to set up the airflow. I've a pyenv installed in another drive. I've binded the volume with pyenv while creating the airflow containers. I've also updated env variable PATH in the containers to point to the python versions available in pyenv volume mounted. But airflow is still making use of the python  (3.7.7) that comes with image apache/airflow:2.3.3. Is it possible to make airflow use a different python environment? I'm looking for if there is some additional environment variables that need to be updated so that airflow will take another python environment.

Answer (score 0):

Have you taken a look at

- [PythonVirtualenvOperator](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/howto/operator/python.html#pythonvirtualenvoperator)
- [ExternalPythonOperator](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/howto/operator/python.html#externalpythonoperator) <-- this might require an upgrade to 2.4.0

Both of these offer flexibility call Python callables inside new Python environments.

Comment: It helped. Thanks a lot to pointing in the right direction